# how to get Current internet IP in ASP.NET MVC when working on localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a Asp.net MVC web Application.I want to detect the user IP address where he/she currently use my application , on the bases of this ip i want to set some functionalities in this web application. I am using=

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
{
    ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
}
else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
{
    ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
}
```

it will never goes to if part of the code because HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] it returned equal to null
In else part it is always provide me IP of localhost ie. 127.0.0.1 ,  but i want to get my current internet IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User's IP address can be retrieved by using:

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

or

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

Comment: MR. cool   it is providing  ip '127.0.0.1' on my localhost that's my major problem.

Comment: try to host it on IIS and see if what value it returns.

Comment: Just a heads up, in some cases Request.UserHostAddress can be null. I would wrap it around something or check first before using it.